# validating read access to specified authenticated user

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I'm planning to create a realtime database for a chatting apps with private message channel, is there any specific rules that we can check the authenticated user has access to this room?

my database structure is mostly like this:

```
{
  "channel": {
       "unique_room_id": {
            "participants": {
                 "uid1": 1537259273000,
                 "uid2": 1537259273000
            }
            "message": {
                 ....
            }
       }
   }
}
```

Is it possible to use hasChild like how it is used on .write rule or we need to manually validate the reference which means it's not really possible to add more participants to the room?

If possible I want to avoid the latter, thanks in advance

Note:

I'm also open to any alternative structures, and maybe some explanation why it is recommended

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's always easiest to use top-level lists instead of nesting multiple entity types in a single list. So remodel your data to:

```
{
    "participants": {
        "unique_room_id": {
            "uid1": 1537259273000,
            "uid2": 1537259273000
        }
    }
    "messages": {
        "unique_room_id": {
             ....
        }
    }
}
```

Now you can ensure that only participants in a room can read its messages with:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "messages": {
      "$roomid": {
        ".read": "root.child('participants').child($roomid).child(auth.uid).exists()"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried using .child($roomid) and when deploying using firebase-tools it returned an error that it expects a string, will a single-quote on the $roomid will be parsed as variable on firebase or it will be parsed as normal string?

Comment: There should be no quotes around `$roomid` in `.child($roomid)`, otherwise it will be seen as an ordinary string. If Firebase complains about not knowing `$roomid`, check whether you've given it the exact same name under `"messages": {`.
      "$roomid": {

Comment: ah yes, it works, it has typo on the upper level nodes. thanks for the help